# External table syntax error ORA-29913

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have created the below external tables, but I am not able to retrieve data using select * from emp as I get the error below.

Can you please help me on this.

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout ORA-29400: data
>   cartridge error KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access
>   parameters KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one
>   of: "compression, encryption, logfile, nologfile, version" KUP-01008:
>   the bad identifier was: RECORDS KUP-01007: at line 1 column 1

My SQL is:

```
create or replace directory dit as  'C:\Hi'

GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY dit TO sys;
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY dit TO sys;

GRANT SELECT ON dba_directories TO sys;

CREATE  TABLE emp(ename char(20), sal number) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
 (TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
DEFAULT DIRECTORY dit 
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
NOBADFILE
LOGFILE 'Hi.log'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(ename char(20), sal number)
)
LOCATION('Hi.txt')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `TYPE ORACLE_LOADER` if the data is in txt file.

The `TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP` uses binary files, so the `RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE` wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you for your response....but still am getting the same error message...Can anyone please help me out

Comment: Oracle_loader is not supporting number datatype...its working after i changed it to char datatype....

Comment: The datatypes supported by the `oracle_loader` driver are listed at [docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm#sthref1759). There is no `number` but there is `integer`, `double`, `float` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and this parameter solved my problem:

```
REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
```

try to add it into your ACCESS PARAMETERS

My Organization External was like this

```
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY SYNCFILESTESTE
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
        records delimited by newline
        fields terminated by ';'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
     )
     LOCATION ('teste.csv')
  );
```